# React Native Parse.File, what should I be giving it as an input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-server

I have to upload some images to my Parse server, the documentation says

```
var file = new Parse.File("myfile.zzz", fileData, "image/png");
```

But it is not clear what I should be using as `fileData`.

I tried using `require("path/to/image")` but this return an integer, not the image itself.
I also tried to use `{uri: "path/to/image"}` because these are the two methods I know for using an image in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

[Parse File API documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.File.html) is quite clear about what is the second parameter of `File`. It can be a byte value, base64 encoded string or a file object selected with upload control.

> **name    String**
>
> The file's name. This will be prefixed by a unique value
>   once the file has finished saving. The file name must begin with an
>   alphanumeric character, and consist of alphanumeric characters,
>   periods, spaces, underscores, or dashes.
>
> **data    Array**
>
> The data for the file, as either:
>
> 1. an Array of byte value Numbers, or
> 2. an Object like { base64: "..." } with a base64-encoded String.
> 3. a File object selected with a file upload control. (3) only works    in Firefox 3.6+, Safari 6.0.2+, Chrome 7+, and IE 10+.    For
>      example: var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
>      if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) { var file =
>      fileUploadControl.files[0]; var name = "photo.jpg"; var parseFile =
>      new Parse.File(name, file); parseFile.save().then(function() { // The
>      file has been saved to Parse. }, function(error) { // The file either
>      could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse. }); }
>
> **type    String**
>
> Optional Content-Type header to use for the file. If this
>   is omitted, the content type will be inferred from the name's
>   extension.

Comment: Ok then, so my question was badly posed.
I was having trouble getting the image file itself